# Is there any way to implement following JSON pojo class and how to pass data to list?

Tags: java, android, json, arraylist, retrofit2

[image: JSON file]

**API Call**

```
@POST("api/CustomerOrder/Post")
Call<ResponseBody> postData(@Body Example orderDetail);
```

**MODEL CLASS**

```
public class Example extends BaseResponse {

@SerializedName("CustId")
@Expose
private String custId;
@SerializedName("distId")
@Expose
private String distId;
@SerializedName("Description")
@Expose
private String description;
@SerializedName("lstCustomerOrderDetails")
@Expose
ArrayList<LstCustomerOrderDetail> orderDetails; //added get set}
```

**Calling API**

```
mService.postData(exampleResponse)
            .enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                    try {
                        String s =response.body().string();
                        Toast.makeText(ExampleActivity.this, s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        textView.setText(s);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                    Toast.makeText(ExampleActivity.this, t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
```

**List Class**

```
public class LstCustomerOrderDetail {
@SerializedName("PtypeId")
@Expose
private String ptypeId;
@SerializedName("SubptypeId")
@Expose
private String subptypeId;
@SerializedName("productimgurl")
@Expose
private String productimgurl;
@SerializedName("subproductimgurl")
@Expose
private String subproductimgurl;
@SerializedName("Quantity")
@Expose
private String quantity;
@SerializedName("Rate")
@Expose
private String rate;
@SerializedName("Totalamount")
@Expose
private String totalamount;
@SerializedName("Paymentmode")
@Expose
private String paymentmode;
@SerializedName("Paymentstatus")
@Expose
private String paymentstatus;
```

**How to add data to all JSON custId... lstCustomerOrderDetails[]?**
I am getting data submitted to server successfully, but data is not stored in database.

i have also added list class, now my question is how to add data to Model class and list class?

Comment: If the data is getting to the server successfully, then you probably need to debug on the server

Comment: @Omodemilade Bamgbose Thank you... but i already debug the code data is going everything is ok.. just tell me i am doing code in right way or not? and please tell me how to pass data to Model class

Comment: can you also show this class `LstCustomerOrderDetail` @DeepakRakh

Comment: `public class LstCustomerOrderDetail {
    @SerializedName("PtypeId")
    @Expose
    private String ptypeId;
    @SerializedName("SubptypeId")
    @Expose
    private String subptypeId;
    @SerializedName("productimgurl")
    @Expose
    private String productimgurl;
    @SerializedName("subproductimgurl")
    @Expose
    private String subproductimgurl;
    @SerializedName("Quantity")
    @Expose
    private String quantity;
    @SerializedName("Rate")
    ;` and other feilds added also

Answer (score 0):

looks like `private String custId` and `private String distId` should be integers

Comment: i think that's not a issue. can you write little bit of code how to add data to Model Class and List and integrate that class in API call